# Chain populate HTML select boxes using AJAX, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

My special form has two select boxes. I got the first one populate with options from a MySQL database using PHP, during page loading stage.

What I'm trying to achieve next is the following:

By selecting one of the values from first pre-populated `<select>` box - the second `<select>` box gets populated with relevant data from a database table based on what option was selected in the first `<select>` box.

So, following the image below, if I select a location from the first `<select>` box, then the second `<select>` box will be populated with all the suites that are at that location.

[image]

My database has all the data already in place and relations set up. I've tested my SQL queries on the database side and they work. Now I needed to put it all into a PHP script that would be called via AJAX call from the form.

What I've done so far is try to send `$.ajax` request from this form to a PHP script called `jQueryHelper.php` and that script in turn should return suites which I'll `alert()` for the beginning.

jQueryHelper.php:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_NAME", "mydb");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "**********");

class jQueryHelper
{
    private static $initialized = false;
    private $db_connection = null;

    private static function initialize()
    {
        if (self::$initialized)
            return;
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        self::$initialized = true;
    }

    public static function giveData()
    {
        self::initialize();
        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
                if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){
                    $action = $_POST['action'];
                    $theSelectedLocationId = $_POST['id'];
                    switch($action){
                        case 'getAssignedSuites': 
                            $this->getAssignedSuites($theSelectedLocationId);
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    public static function getAssignedSuites($theSelectedLocationId){
        $sql =<<<EOF
            SELECT * FROM suites
            WHERE location_id = $theSelectedLocationId
EOF;

        $query_get_assigned_suites = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
        $rows = array();
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_get_assigned_suites)){
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
    }
}

// Call it!
jQueryHelper::giveData();
?>
```

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="user_todays_locations.php" name="updatetodayslocation" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="suite_location" class="sr-only">Assigned Locations</label>
        <select size="1" name="suite_location" class="form-control input-lg" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Assigned Locations</option>
            <?php $location->getAssignedLocations($login->getCurrentUserID()); ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- more divs and form controls here -->
</form>
```

jQuery's `$.ajax`(located in the `<body>` above the `<form>`):

```
<script>
// grab ID of selected location
$(function() {
    $("select[name=suite_location]").change(function() {
        var theSelectedLocationId = this.value;
        //alert(theSelectedLocationId);
        $.ajax({ url: '/classes/jQueryHelper.php',
            data: {action: 'getAssignedSuites', id: theSelectedLocationId},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                alert(output);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

jQuery's `<select>` .change event fires without problem and I get an alert with the value of selected option(in my case it's the ID of the location in the database). The `$.ajax` part, that's nested deeper, doesn't want to work.
Entire website is stored on a LAMP server. Entire website is inside: `/mywebsites/project/www/`
The form is inside `views` folder, which gets included in a script at root level along with other views to display the complete page. `jQueryHelper.php` is inside `classes` folder.

I don't know, maybe there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: it looks like `getAssignedSuites()` just does a `return json_encode($rows);`. You have no echo or print. Possibly a `echo jQueryHelper::giveData();`?

Comment: @Sean Changed that to echo. Still no dice.

Comment: I also added `error` event along with `success` to test it out and indeed I keep getting `error` event fired whenever I invoke `change` event for first `<select>` box.

Comment: I updated the error event further. Whenever I trigger it I catch the `Requested page not found. [404]` alert box.

Comment: If you are getting `404`, then you need to check your browser console to see what url your `$.ajax()` is calling. You are viewing this on your live LAMP server, and not just as a local file, correct?

Comment: Actually I got `$.ajax` to find the script file. I had to put `classes/jQueryHelper.php` instead of `/classes/jQueryHelper.php` since the script that was loading this view was located inside root. But now I have to deal with a few PHP error that tell me that I can't use `$this` and a few other `non-object` errors. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX call couldn't find `jQueryHelper.php`.
Changing `url` from `/classes/jQueryHelper.php` to `classes/jQueryHelper.php` fixed the path issue.

Answer (score 1):

in your switch block, shouldn't you return the result returned from `getAssignedSuites` call?

```
switch($action){
  case 'getAssignedSuites': 
    return $this->getAssignedSuites($theSelectedLocationId);
    break;
}
```

then as @sean suggested. `echo jQueryHelper::giveData();`

also. i don't think it is good practice to call `$_POST` within class function. I suggest to pass them as parameters like `jQueryHelper::giveData($_POST['action'], $_POST['id'])` then use it.

Comment: I don't think so. When I `$this->getAssignedSuites($theSelectedLocationId);` I execute getAssignedSuites() which in turn return/echoes the result. Anyways, I tried that too but I still get AJAX error that says `Requested page not found. [404]`. See updated `<script>` for improved error event.

Comment: hmmm. let's fix that first. are your view.php and jQueryHelper.php in different folder, and is that why you specified url path to be '/classes/jQueryHelper.php'? because, '/~path' is calling the file path from the root.